# Sales Quotataion Confirm Button (Disabled/Enabled) AX Dynamics X++

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I would like to enabled/disabled the `Confirm` (MenuItemButtonName: `ButtonUpdateConfirmation`) button under `Sales and marketing -> Common -> Sales quotation -> All quotation -> Follow up` when selecting records on Grid list. Currently, the `Confirm` button was enabled/disabled when the quotation status is sent/created respectively. I want to alter this behavior for me to disabled/enabled the `Confirm` button when the selected sales quotation was reach the credit limit.

The problem is, I can't find the behavior on where the button was enabled/disabled. Anyone know where is it? I'm currently looking at `SalesQuotationListPage` form

Answer (score 5):

The **update** of `MenuItemButton` `ButtonUpdateConfirmation` is in `SalesQuotationTableForm class` in `enableUpdateButtonsMultiselect()` method.

Here passed four parameters `FormFunctionButtonControl`. For the `MenuItembutton` `ButtonUpdateConfirmation` **this is the param:**

```
FormFunctionButtonControl  buttonUpdateConfirmation
```

In this method you can change behavior on where the button was enabled/disabled.

Comment: I try to comment out all codes under enableUpdateButtonMultiSelect() method but there's no effect on the current behavior of the said button. It seems that this method is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, I check this code, perform some test and work fine, in `enableUpdateButtonsMultiselect()` method, line 68 `buttonUpdateConfirmation.enabled(enableConfirmationButton);` this button change his enabled property. if you put this: `buttonUpdateConfirmation.enabled(true);` set the button enabled. and this for disabled `buttonUpdateConfirmation.enabled(false);`. And debug this code because there is a return before this code.